# Set method does not set the properties of an abstract object through Moq

Tags: c#, moq

I have a `SetRange` method, that sets `StartDate` and `EndDate` properties:

```
public virtual void SetRange(DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
{
    this.StartDate = startDate;
    this.EndDate = endDate;
}
```

In test on my stub object, below will set the `StartDate` and `EndDate` properties:

```
var dateRangeEntityStub = new Mock<DateRangeEntityBase>();
dateRangeEntityStub.SetupAllProperties();
// atempt 1
dateRangeEntityStub.Object.SetRange(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1), DateTime.Now);
// atempt 2
dateRangeEntityStub.Setup(x => x.SetRange(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1), DateTime.Now));
```

But the normal setter will work:

```
dateRangeEntityStub.Object.EndDate = DateTime.Now;
```

Why `SetRange` method doesn't set the properties on stub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moq overrides every virtual method/property and will use its own implementation for it.

So if you want to keep the original behaviour of your `SetRange` method you need set the `CallBase` to `true` on your mock which tells Moq to also invoke your original code:

```
var dateRangeEntityStub = new Mock<DateRangeEntityBase>() { CallBase = true };
```

See also in the quickstart's: [Customizing Mock Behavior](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#customizing-mock-behavior) section.